# copyOf method undefined for the type Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, object, copy, system

```
elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, newCapacity);
```

Gives error:

> The method copyOf(Object[], int) is undefined for the type Arrays

This was not a problem on my home computer, but at my school's it gives the error above.  I'm guessing it's running an older JRE version - any workaround?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Arrays.copyOf()` was introduced in 1.6.

You'd need to create a new array of the size you need and copy the contents of the old array into it.

From: http://www.source-code.biz/snippets/java/3.htm

```
/**
* Reallocates an array with a new size, and copies the contents
* of the old array to the new array.
* @param oldArray  the old array, to be reallocated.
* @param newSize   the new array size.
* @return          A new array with the same contents.
*/
private static Object resizeArray (Object oldArray, int newSize) {
   int oldSize = java.lang.reflect.Array.getLength(oldArray);
   Class elementType = oldArray.getClass().getComponentType();
   Object newArray = java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(
         elementType,newSize);
   int preserveLength = Math.min(oldSize,newSize);
   if (preserveLength > 0)
      System.arraycopy (oldArray,0,newArray,0,preserveLength);

   return newArray; 
}
```

Answer (score 8):

From the [javadocs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28T[],%20int%29):

> **Since:**
>           1.6

So yes, your school is apparently using Java 1.5 or older. Two solutions are:

1. Upgrade it (however, I'd first consult the school's system admin ;) ).
2. Write your own utility method which does the same task (it's [open source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/jdk7-b76/src/share/classes/java/util/Arrays.java) (line 2908)).

Comment: Good idea.. (for 2), I never think about this way. Now I have one more and best solution.

Answer (score 3):

`Arrays.copyOf` was introduced in 1.6.  One work around would be to upgrade to 1.6.  Another is to use `System.arraycopy` (see: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html )

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you have different versions of Java on different computers.

`Arrays.copyOf` is new in `Java 1.6`.